# Is it better to try for one mega screen scraper or split it into a scraper for different sites?

Tags: php, web-crawler, web-scraping

I will explain my situation.

Our Social Media Manager (yay) suddenly wants something to scrape a list of about 40 websites for information about our company, for example there's a lot of review sites in the list.

(I have read a ton of tutorials and SO questions but still) My questions are:

1. Is it possible to build a generic scraper that will work across all of these sites or do I need a separate scraper for each site?
2. I think I understand how to parse an individual web page but how do you do it, where, for example there's a website structure of `review-website.com/company-name` and on that page are titles and a snippet of the review that then link to the actual full page review?

i.e. Crawling and scraping multiple pages on multiple sites. Some are 'easier' than others because they have dedicated pages like the urls previously mentioned but some are forums etc with no particular structure that just happen to mention our company name so I don't know how to get relevant information on those.

1. Does the time spent creating this justify that the Social Media Manager could just search these sites manually himself? Especially considering that a HTML change on any of the sites could possibly end up breaking the scraper?

I really don't think this is a good idea yet my Line Manager seems to think it will take a morning's worth of work to write a scraper for all of these sites and I have no idea how to do it!

**UPDATE**

Thank you very much for the answers so far, I also thought I'd provide a list of the sites just to clarify what I think is an extreme task:

`Facebook - www.facebook.com`

`Social Mention - www.socialmention.com`

`Youtube - www.youtube.com`

`Qype - www.qype.co.uk`

`Money Saving Expert - www.moneysavingexpert.co.uk`

`Review Centre - www.reviewcentre.com`

`Dooyoo - www.dooyoo.co.uk`

`Yelp - www.yelp.co.uk`

`Ciao - www.ciao.co.uk`

`All in London - www.allinlondon.co.uk`

`Touch Local  - www.touchlocal.com`

`Tipped - www.tipped.co.uk`

`What Clinic - www.whatclinic.com`

`Wahanda - www.wahanda.com`

`Up My Street - www.upmystreet.com`

`Lasik Eyes - www.lasik-eyes.co.uk/`

`Lasik Eyes (Forum) - forums.lasik-eyes.co.uk/default.asp`

`Laser Eye Surgery - www.laser-eye-surgery-review.com/`

`Treatment Saver - www.treatmentsaver.com/lasereyesurgery`

`Eye Surgery Compare - www.eyesurgerycompare.co.uk/best-uk-laser-eye-surgery-clinics`

`The Good Surgeon Guide - www.thegoodsurgeonguide.co.uk/`

`Private Health -www.privatehealth.co.uk/hospitaltreatment/find-a-treatment/laser-eye-surgery/`

`Laser Eye Surgery Wiki - www.lasereyesurgerywiki.co.uk`

`PC Advisor - www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/2/consumerwatch/`

`Scoot - www.scoot.co.uk`

`Cosmetic Surgery Reviews - www.cosmetic-surgery-reviews.co.uk`

`Lasik Reviews - www.lasikreviews.co.uk`

`Laser Eye Surgery Costs - www.lasereyesurgerycosts.co.uk`

`Who Calls Me - www.whocallsme.com`

`Treatment Adviser - www.treatmentadviser.com/`

`Complaints Board - http://www.complaintsboard.com`

`Toluna - http://uk.toluna.com/`

`Mums Net - http://www.mumsnet.com`

`Boards.ie - http://www.boards.ie`

`AV Forums - http://www.avforums.com`

`Magic Mum - http://www.magicmum.com`

Comment: Btw, you may want to point your manager towards the company Legal department, to check whether you're even allowed to scrape those sites.

Comment: A little thing that is often overlooked by people making scrapers: Be sure to respect `robots.txt`. It's not there just because of the cool filename. Keep in mind that the presence of a robots.txt doesn't mean you may copy everything that isn't mentioned in it. It's a blacklist, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really deppends on what sort of websites and data you face.

**Option 1: DOM / XPATH based**

If you need to parse tables and very detailed things you need to parse each site with a separate algorithm. One way would be to parse each of the specific site into a DOM representation and adress each value per XPATH. This will take some time and is affected by structure changes and if you have to scrape each of these sites with this it will cost you more than a morning.

**Option 2: Density based**

However if you need to parse something like a blog article and you may want to extract only the articles text there are pretty good density based algorithm which work accross HTML structure changes. One of those is described here: https://www2.cs.kuleuven.be/cwis/research/liir/publication_files/978AriasEtAl2009.pdf

A implementation is provided here: http://apoc.sixserv.org/code/ce_density.rb

You would have to port it to php. For blogs and news sites this is a really effective way.

**Option 3: Pragmatic**

If you do not care about layout and structure and only want to have the data provided. You might download contents and try to strip the tags solely. However this will have a lot of noise in the resulting text.

**Update**

After updating your post you might follow the following in order:

1. Check which page is illegal to scrape. On this list there are for sure some which you will not be allowed to scrape.
2. You will need much more time than a day. I would talk about this and the legal problems with project lead.
3. Choose one option per page

Answer (score 0):

1. I would create a scraper for each site but create a library with common functionality (e.g. opening up a page, convert to DOM, report errors, storing results etc)
2. Try to avoid regular expressions when scraping. A small change will stop the scraping working. Use the web sites DOM structure instead (XPaths?). Much more reliable.
3. Tell your boss it is going take quite a bit of time.
4. Good luck.